# Gray background when scanning a line drawing

Tags: background, drawing

[image]When I scan a line drawing on my Canon 9000F scanner I get the scanner reading the white paper the drawing is on as gray. In other words, the background is smudgy, not pure white. Someone suggested putting black paper on top of the drawing because the cover lining that goes against the picture is white. Anybody have any ideas how to fix this. I'm told the scanner intensity cannot be adjusted.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You really should read the scanner user manual. If you don't have it you can download it direct from the [Canon website](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/scanners/support-scanners-canoscan-series/canoscan-9000f#manuals_tab)

I too have a Canon 9000F, and it is entirely possible to make adjustments to the scan intensity.  The scanner has advanced controls.

Anyhoo, here are the steps:

1. Launch the MP Navigator,
2. Click on "Scan" in the MP Navigator
3. Select the "Use the scanner driver" option.
4. Then when you hit the Scan button, the ScanGear scanner driver will launch.
5. Click on the Advanced tab
6. Hit Preview, then make contrast, brightness, or curves adjustments as required. The controls are at the bottom right of the ScanGear window, just above the Preview button.

[image]

In the example above, I've added a curves adjustment to make sure the white is white, and to darken the pencil lines.

BTW, what NOT to do is launch the scanner via the WIA support for the scanner in Photoshop - it's crap, and far too basic. Always use the proper scanner driver. You can always open the scanned image later in Photoshop, or whatever software you use.

Comment: I have uploaded how a line drawing looks when I scan it on my Canon 9000F and then how it is printed on a Samsung ML-2510 monochrome laser printer. Can it be a printer problem?